# How to squash git commits after doing a merge

Tags: git, github, merge, rebase, squash

I have a pull request where my original commit wasn't passing tests. I didn't look at it for a while and came back to it after a number of months. During this time the upstream repo had done a bunch of commits, so I merged them into my repo. I then added a commit that fixed the broken tests.

I'd like to squash my pull request into a single commit. I have:

```
2102f91 <-- original commit from Jan 2015
c202023 <-- merge from upstream Feb 2016
df22e9c <-- commit to fix tests Feb 2016
```

Is it possible to squash this or is it easier to delete the branch and redo my pull request?

Comment: Looking at the commit history, it seems like your commits are not on their own branch, as `c202023` is between them. But then you mention the possibility of "deleting the branch". So are your commits on master, or on their own branch?

Comment: Sorry, yes this is on its own branch

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already pushed your existing branch (let's call it old_branch), I wouldn't rewrite it. Instead, I would create a new branch off of the latest master (let's call it new_branch). Then we can do a "squash merge":

```
git checkout master -b new_branch
git merge old_branch --squash
```

Now new_branch will contain a single commit with all of the stuff done in old_branch.